# Uploading app to client account in app store

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

This is my first time trying to upload app to app store, so I am completely lost. I have searched all over the web about the issue I am having, but could not find how to fix the issue.

Here is the problem:

I have developed an updated version for the existing iPhone app for client. Original version of app is already in app store for long time. Client wants me to upload new version of the app to their account in app store as "prerelease" for testing. They gave me their store account (admin role) username and password to log in. I added the account in Xcode and configured build settings to their team. But, after building the archive, when I click the "Validate" button and select their team, I am getting an error popup with the message "***Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate***". I can't post images here, so here is snapshot image of the popup):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/keb0y.jpg

Apple troubleshooting documentation ([documentation link here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH5-SW2)) shows that they should export developer profile and give me to import on my Mac. However, client say they don't have Mac and no Xcode, so they can't do it themselves. Apple documentation is mentioning another option - “Revoke and Request”, but I can't see that option. Also, if "revoke" is performed, will that affect client's application (more than 20 apps in app store)?

I have downloaded all of their certificates and profiles from Member center, imported to keychain, added account to Xcode, configured Xcode, but nothing helped.

Does anyone know what can I do, or ask to client, so that I can upload app to their app store account?

Thank you!

Comment: First of all check from where they generated certificate for signing request (From which computer).

They must have generated .csr file for generating certificate .

and another thing they must need xcode to upload build so ask them about that from where they uploaded build .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have downloaded the Distribution certificate from the account. That alone is not sufficient. You must get the private key from the client or developer who has created the certificate first or uploaded the application.

Comment: You are right. After they gave me their distribution private key, I could do what was needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in to [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) portal, using the required credentials.
2. Click on "*Manage your certificates, App IDs, devices, and provisioning profiles*." under **Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles**
3. Then click on "*Certificates*"
4. On the new page Click on "**+**" button at right upper corner.
5. Now on this page select "*App Store and Ad Hoc*" under **Production**.
6. Then follow the instructions related to **CSR** file given on new page.

*Note: Create new certificates with unique names so that you won't download old certificates to your mac, mistakenly.*

For more info [Distributing iOS Apps With iTunes Connect](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/distributing-ios-apps-with-itunes-connect--cms-21672)

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. However, my issue was solved by getting distribution private key from the client.